# How can I reduce the database call time and number (Rails)?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I'm working on a rails app for a building that keeps track of water usage/collection and electricity use/solar generation, etc. These are stored as measurement rows, attached to sensors, which are attached to programs (location in the building, essentially) and subtypes (attached to types - water, electricity).

I'm doing some graphing with chartkick, and the database calls related to this are way too slow. They'll be much faster on the production servers, but there will also be far more data.

Here's the helper method that has the chart generation and database call in it:

```
def stackedSubtypeChart(grouping)
rsubs = @resource.subtypes
            .order(:usage?) #add usage types after gen types
            .map{|stype| [
                stype.name,stype.measurements #this takes too long!
                .where("date >= ?", params[:start]) #(4 calls!!)
                .where("date <= ?", params[:stop])
                .group_by_period(grouping, :date).maximum(:amount)]}

rsubs = rsubs.map {|stype|
                    {name: stype[0],
                    data: stype[1]}}

ret = column_chart rsubs,
                    stacked: true,
                    library: { :series => {0 => { type: "line"}}}
end
```

@resource is defined in the controller as:

```
@resource = Type.includes(:subtypes => :sensors).find_by_resource('electricity')
```

I've commented the line that's responsible for there being multiple calls, which is definitely part of the problem. This takes two seconds to load on my (admittedly very very old) computer with a month of data.

I could really use help with both changing the map so that this is one call instead of however-many-subtypes calls, and with reducing what I'm pulling in so each call isn't taking half a second. I don't have a ton of experience optimizing this sort of thing and I'm not really sure how to start doing more than I have here already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of bashing my head against a wall, I stumbled across this, which is a much faster single query that grabs all the data + data connections I need. It's a little hard to format but it works.

```
rsubs = Measurement
          .where("measurements.date >= ? AND measurements.date <= ?",
              offset(params[:start], -1, grouping),
              offset(params[:stop], 1, grouping))
          .joins(sensor: {subtype: :type})
          .where("types.resource = ?", @rname)
          .order('subtypes."usage?"')
          .group_by_period(grouping, :date).group("subtypes.id, subtypes.name").maximum(:amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be helpful to look into ActiveRecord Explain to dig into the SQL.  There's a good [screencast](https://gorails.com/episodes/activerecord-explain) that explains (pun totally intended) pretty well.